# Jquery steps with ajax confirmtion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Good afternoon, I am stuck with my code. So basically what I am trying to do is checking if the database is connected and **if yes** **move to the next step and if not stay in the same step just showing an alert.** BUT even when its not connected it is going to the next step....

> What I have so far:

TOP OF THE PAGE:

```
if (isset($_POST['credentials'])) {
// Database credentials
define('DBHOST', $_POST['database_host']);
define('DBUSER', $_POST['database_name']);
define('DBNAME', $_POST['database_username']);
define('DBPASS', $_POST['database_password']);

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   echo 'Connected';
exit;   

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
}


}
```

*BOTTOM OF THE PAGE IN script tag*:

```
$("#wizard").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "none",
    titleTemplate: '<span class="number">#index#</span><span class="bd-wizard-step-title">#title#</span>',
    
    onStepChanged: function(event, currentIndex, priorIndex){
        if (currentIndex == 1) {
            var database_host = $('#hostname').val();
            var database_name = $('#name').val();
            var database_username = $('#username').val();
            var database_password = $('#password').val();
            
            
            $.ajax({
                 url  : "<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>",
                 type : "POST",
                 async: false, 
                 dataType: 'text',
                 data : 
                 {
                    'credentials' : 1,
                    'database_host' : database_host,
                    'database_name' : database_name,
                    'database_username' : database_username,
                    'database_password' : database_password
                 },
                success:function(re){
                    if (re == "Connected") {
                        alert("Connected");
                    } else {
                        alert("Rejected");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas how to solve it? I would be much appreciated

P.S: I already put "return false;" but still going to the next step...

[I am using http://www.jquery-steps.com](http://www.jquery-steps.com)

Comment: Async false wont help here, because your response from PHP is going to be considered a 'success' callback regardless (it returned a 200 code with body). Return false in the success is only returning false from that function (which goes nowhere).

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is async by default you would need to set async to false I believe: [jQuery wizard steps move before ajax call completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203037/jquery-wizard-steps-move-before-ajax-call-completed/35937645)

Comment: As you can see the async is false already in my code..

Comment: Ah sorry just saw that, are you sure it is not throwing an error? Try adding an error handler perhaps and see if that's the issue?